# haskell error- parse error on input '='

Tags: haskell

I am compiling this code and receving the error of "parse error on input '='`

```
import System.IO  
import Data.List.Split
main = do  
   handle <- openFile "ac/abc" ReadMode  
   contents <- hGetContents handle  
   let xs = splitOneOf "; \n " contents       
   print xs   
   readStrList contents = do 
       print contents
   hClose handle
```

please suggest what is wrong

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the `readStrList` line?

Comment: actually i was trying another way of recursion as forM_ requires hoogle.this worked.thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is in these lines:

```
readStrList contents = do 
    print contents
```

If you're trying to define `readStrList`, then you need to put `let` in front:

```
let readStrList contents = do
        print contents
```

Comment: But that definition wouldn't do anything, since `contents` would shadow the outer `contents`, and the function is never called. (Not saying you're wrong, just that I can't make heads or tails of what the line is trying to do, but that's probably not it.)

Comment: @Chuck: I assumed that it was intended to be used later on within the `do` block. But I agree, it's difficult to tell what's intended here.